# DataGridView сложный hedertext из нескольких стобцов

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

знаю что подобные вопросы задавали уже. Но все же, вдруг, что изменилось и теперь есть простое решение)
Беда в том, что проект написан на WindowsForm и необходимо изготовить вот такое вот чудо из DataGridView.
[image: Чудо дивное]

Знаю, что winForm не умеют это делать сами. 
А теперь вопросы:

**-Куда копать, если пытаться сделать это через winForm?**

**-Или может проще забыть про winForm и переписать на WPF?(Его не знаю совсем, если будьте советовать переписать, то было бы круто получить ссылку на хороший ресурс про него)**

Еще подумываю про такой странный вариант, как попробовать использовать TableLayout, как то, но не знаю возможно ли его динамически заполнить. Да им геморройно должно быть это, как я понимаю, потому что форма по сути с отчетом и данные всегда будут разные и разное их количество....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если форма нужна для отчета рекомендую вам `Toolbox -> ReportViewer` в нем можете составить отчет с таблицей при этом есть возможность сохранить отчет в pdf/word/excel